# Create a couchbase bucket using c#

Tags: c#, .net, couchbase

I need to create bucket and indexes using code. I tried with CreateBucketAsync method but it ask for 'ManagemenUri' in cluster object and my cluster object don't have it. I have observed that ManagementUri appears in cluster object only after doing a BucketAsync.
so please can you advice how to create a bucket in c#?

```
await cluster.Buckets.CreateBucketAsync(bucketSettings);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use the Bucket management API, you'll need to open a connection to Couchbase which will then populate the ManagementUri internally. For example:

```
var cluster = await Cluster.ConnectAsync("couchbase://localhost", _options);
var bucketManager = cluster.Buckets;
await bucketManager.CreateBucketAsync(//your settings here//);
```

The "management uri" which is used internally to post the request is derived from the server cluster config fetched from the server when you call ConnectAsync.

That being said, I suspect that your doing this and then encountering a NulReferenceException that points to the ManagementUri? If this is the case the connection to the server never successfully happened and you are seeing a side effect of this (which is the incorrect error message).

I would verify that the connection is correctly being made. You can do this by [enabling logging](https://docs.couchbase.com/dotnet-sdk/current/howtos/collecting-information-and-logging.html) and then checking to see how the bootstrapping went. Additionally, I created a [Jira ticket](https://issues.couchbase.com/browse/NCBC-3239) for improving the error message here so that its easier to understand why its failing.